Rigorous Proof that $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \leq 0$ in Fermat's Stationary Point Theorem?
Title: Rigorous Proof that $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \leq 0$ in Fermat's Stationary Point Theorem
Body:(Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#Proof_2:_Extremum_implies_derivative_vanishes)
In the proof of Fermat's Stationary Point Theorem, consider the following scenario:
Suppose that $x_0$ is a local maximum (a similar proof applies if $x_0$ is a local minimum). Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \subset (a, b)$ and
$$
f(x_0) \geq f(x)
$$
for all $x$ with $|x - x_0| < \delta$.
Hence, for any $h \in (0, \delta)$, we have
$$
\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \leq 0.
$$
Since the limit of this ratio as $h$ approaches $0$ from above exists and is equal to $f'(x_0)$, we conclude that
$$
f'(x_0) \leq 0.
$$
On the other hand, for $h \in (-\delta, 0)$, we notice that
$$
\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \geq 0.
$$
Question:
How does the inequality
$$
\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \leq 0 \quad \text{for} \quad h > 0
$$
rigorously lead to the conclusion that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \leq 0?
$$
Intuitively, it makes sense because the function approaches values less than or equal to zero since it is ITSELF always less than or equal to zero. However, the rigorous logic seems unclear because the limit is not the function value itself but a value such that its absolute difference from the function (bounded on an interval near zero) is smaller than any aribitaray positive epsilon.
Specifically, how can we prove that this limit is less than or equal to zero rigorously? Should we use the epsilon-delta definition if necessary?

The epsilon-delta definition is necessary since an argument about limits must invoke the definition of limit. In many situations there may be a theorem based on that definition that you can use, which would avoid going all the way back.

I don't think there's any well-known theorem we can use here. Probably have to directly derive something from the definition that's usually just part of the intuition?

Yes, go back to the definiton. Proving intuitivley obvious assertions like this one is good practice using the definition.

Think about the contrapositive. If the limit as $x\to a$ of a function is positive, then the function must be positive sufficiently close to (but not necessarily at) $a$. Yes, the definition of limit is still required.

My approach is proving it by contradiction:
$f(x_0)$ is a maximum so $f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)\le 0$ when $h\in(-\gamma,\gamma)$ for some $\gamma>0$. Furthermore
$$
\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} \leq 0\;\; \text{for}\;\; h > 0
$$
reasoning by absurdity, if
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}>0
$$
then by Theorem of sign permanence there would exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}>0$$ for each $h\in(0,\delta)$. therefore choosing $h<\min\{\gamma, \delta\}$ leads to a contradiction, because $$
f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)\le0\implies\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}\le 0
$$

In Italian this theorem is known exactly as the translation of "Theorem of sign permanence", but I'm not sure this is the term used in English. I couldn't find any references so I wonder if this is actually used in some books/papers

I found these results as a reference link1, link2

@DavideMasi: I have seen it mentioned as "sign preserving property" but don't know if this is standard term, but definitely conveys the meaning.

@ParamanandSingh thanks!
